# mediaelement.js wordpress plugin - volume is muted when mp3 played in Firefox

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm using the mediaelement.js Wordpress Plugin.

Whenever I play an mp3 in Firefox 3.6 or 5 it starts muted, and then I must adjust volume and I can hear the audio.  Strangely, the volume control is all the way at the top, so it should not be muted.

I've tested in IE9 and do not experience this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, a fix, I unzipped and uploaded all from the build folder to the mediaelement folder in Plugins. Below are files from the 2.1.9 release and also fixes some other issues, such as the Andriod issue.

https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/tree/master/build

Comment: Just tried your solution. Problem still remains.
No audio in Firefox 7.0.1 Any other idea?